# ZF2 apigility - How can we validate collections in json data

Tags: php, validation, collections, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

How can I get validated json value using Apigility. For example, I need to get validated `user_id` under `users` collection in the following json data.

```
{   
    "log_type": "split food",   
    "meal_type": "Break Fast",  
    "meal_date": "12-2-2015",   
    "users": [
        {
            "user_id": 1,
            "food_details": [
                {
                   "food_id":101
                }
            ]
        }
    ] 
}
```

I know fields can be validated through apigility but here is from json.

Thank you

Comment: Never used apigility, but if you can validate arrays, or object, use json_decode and cast it like $fields = (array)json_decode($yourJson); or (\Zend\Any\Class)json_decode($yourJson);

Answer (score 3):

You should look into the documentation of ZF2 validation for validating (form) collections. [Some documentation on this can be found here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html#adding-new-elements-dynamically).
You should set the `type` field like this:

```
'type' => 'Zend\InputFilter\CollectionInputFilter',
```

for validation of nested objects (or form field sets) you need to set the `type` field as follows:

```
'type' => 'Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter'
```

You use it like this:

```
'input_filter' => array(                
    'log_type' => array(
        'validators' => array(
            // ... validators ...
        ),
        'filters' => array(
            // ... filters ...
        ),
     ),
    'meal_type' => array(
        'validators' => array(
            // ... validators ...
        ),
        'filters' => array(
            // ... filters ...
        ),
     ),
     'meal_date' => array(
        'validators' => array(
            // ... validators ...
        ),
        'filters' => array(
            // ... filters ...
        ),
     ),
    'users' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'count' => ... optional count ...
        'input_filter' => ... input filter or input filter config to use for each element ...
        'type' => 'Zend\InputFilter\CollectionInputFilter',
    ),
    'some_complex_element' => array(
        'property_of_complex_element' => array(
            'name' => 'property_of_complex_element',
            'required' => false,
            'validators' => array(
                // ... validators ...
            ),
            'filters' => array(
                // ... filters ...
            ),
        ),
        'type' => 'Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter',
     )          
),
```

An example on how to use this can be found [here on stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16303090/1697459)

To achieve what you want you most likely have to combine those two solutions. Not sure if it is the easiest way to do it, but it is definitely possible!

### EDIT

*For people who haven't setup validation at all yet:*

For content validation in `Apigility` You have to use the [`zfcampus/zf-content-validation` module](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-content-validation) and follow the documentation for configuration. This module allows you to configure your input-filters and validators in a `input_filter_spec` like you would normally do for form validation in ZF2. Here inside these `input-filter` config arrays you can use the configs that I referenced above.

So first properly install that module and once set-up you will be able to use these validation types in `Apigility`.

Comment: This is about ZF Form validation. I was asking, how it can be in apigility.

Comment: @shemeermali I thought you already had your validation set up. You should use the `zf-content-validation` module for validation of your json data and then you can use these configs that I mentioned above.