# zf2 input names as array

Tags: php, zend-framework, input, zend-framework2

In my application I would like to use serval inputs in the way of `name="inputname[]` .

This because I have a form to add more than one child names on a parent. I am wondering how ZF2 works with this procedure?

Comment: You you specify exactly what you mean by "I am wondering how ZF2 works with this procedure?".  I suspect you have a more specific question in mind than the one you are asking.

Comment: Look at http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.collections.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about form collections. There is a lot of documentation available on collections.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html

or link proposed by @venca

http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.collections.html

If you are more specific in your question then the answer can also be more specific.

For validating collections inside a parent I can refer to [my answer on another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28691169/1697459).

It is as simple as:

```
'children' => array(
    'required' => true,
    'count' => ... optional count ...
    'input_filter' => ... input filter or input filter config to use for each element ...
    'type' => 'Zend\InputFilter\CollectionInputFilter',
),
```